# ASPX page in DIV with FileUpload Control

Tags: html, asp.net

Scenario:
I have a ASPX (with no form element) let's call it Page A, the form contains a DIV that displays a ASPX page with a FileUpload Control in a form element, Page B.

Requierment:
Submit the form to upload the file, without Page A refreshing or navigating out and displaying the result of the upload in the DIV or Page B.

Problem:
When I hit the submit button to upload the file, the file uploads and Page A turns into Page B.

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PreviousPage` to do this.

1) Create a property in Page A to expose the file name o something else that you need to expose in Page B, for exemple:

```
 public string FileName 
 { 
   get { return fileUpload.FileName; } 
 }
```

2) On the submit button event in Page A redirect to Page B

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   /*Save file here*/
   this.Server.Transfer("~/PageB.aspx");
 }
```

3) Add the directive in Page B aspx that tell which page is the `PreviousPage`:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/PageA.aspx" %>
```

4) Use the public property in Page B to show the result to the user, for exemple put it in a label:

```
Label1.text = this.PreviousPage.FileName;
```

Hopes this help! Take a look here for more info: [How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://forums.asp.net/t/1103805.aspx/)

Comment: Thanks for the help! sorry I got caught on a emergency project and had to stop this one, I completely forgot that I posted this question... I will now continue my research.

Comment: I know is been a while and sorry for not answering on this thread...  I moved and this project was scratch and forgot to check your answer